# Ruby on Rails, Microposts with Photo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am on `RailsTutorial` by `Michael Hartl` on `chapter 10` and did some extra stuff to add a paperclip image to every micropost.  As I added a photo to the `Micropost`, I call it a `Microphoto`.
As now I did the following:

1. Migrating the database correctly

   ```
   class AddPhotoclipToMicrophotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def self.up
       add_column :microphotos, :photoclip_file_name, :string
       add_column :microphotos, :photoclip_content_type, :string
       add_column :microphotos, :photoclip_file_size, :integer
       add_column :microphotos, :photoclip_updated_at, :datetime
     end
     def self.down
       remove_column :microphotos, :photoclip_updated_at
       remove_column :microphotos, :photoclip_file_name
       remove_column :microphotos, :photoclip_content_type
       remove_column :microphotos, :photoclip_file_size
     end
   end
   ```
2. Changing the microphotos model and controller
3. Writing some view

And this is my files:

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  require "paperclip" 
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar,
:avatar_file_name, :avatar_content_type, :avatar_file_size, :avatar_updated_at
  has_secure_password
  has_many :microphotos, dependent: :destroy
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :large => "120x120>", :medium => "48x48>", :thumb => "26x26>" }
  .
  .
  .
  def feed
    # This is preliminary. See "Following users" for the full implementation.
    Microphoto.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end
end
```

**Microphoto Model**

```
class Microphoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :votes_down, :votes_up, :photoclip,
  :photoclip_file_name, :photoclip_content_type, :photoclip_file_size, :photoclip_updated_at
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :photoclip, :styles => { :large => "500x400>", :medium => "100x80>" }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }  
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  default_scope order: 'microphotos.created_at DESC'
end
```

**Microphotos Controller**

```
class MicrophotosController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  def index
  end
  def create
    @microphoto = current_user.microphotos.build(params[:microphoto])
    if @microphoto.save
      flash[:success] = "Your photo has been uploaded successfully!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
  def destroy
  end
end
```

### I want two things to have in my views:

- Show list of all microphotos from all users on his/her home page just for signed_in user
- Show list of all microphotos from current user on his/her own page just for signed_in user
  For first one I have `/views/static_pages/home.html.erb` & `/views/shared/_feed.html.erb` & `/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb` files.
  For second one I have `/views/users/show.html.erb` & `_microphoto.html.erb` files.

**views/static_pages/home.html.erb (Homepage)**

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <div class="span8">
    <h3>Uploaded Photos</h3>
    <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div>Some static page datat</div>
<% end %>
```

**views/shared/_feed.html.erb**

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microphotos">
    <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
  </ol>
<%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

**views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb**

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= image_tag feed_item.photoclip.url(:large) %>
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
  </span>
</li>
```

### I got the first thing to work, but the second one is pending...

**views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
    <% if @user.microphotos.any? %>
      <h3>Microphotos (<%= @user.microphotos.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microphotos">
        <%= render @microphotos %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microphotos %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**views/microphotos/_microphoto.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <%= image_tag @user.microphotos.photoclip.url(:medium) %>
  <span class="content"><%= microphoto.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(microphoto.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
</li>
```

so by visiting the address:
`http://localhost:3000/users/1`, it gives me the following error:

> undefined method `photoclip' for - ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb50829f0

But every microphoto has a photoclip in database.

### Update

To show microphotos from all users on homepage I used this:

```
def feed
  Microphoto
end
```

in my `User model`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because `@user.microphotos` is set of `microphotos` instead of single `microphoto` record. You should rather do:

```
  <%= render @user.microphotos %>
</ol>
<%= will_paginate @user.microphotos %>
```

in your `views/users/show.html.erb` and:

```
<%= image_tag microphoto.photoclip.url(:medium) %>
```

in `views/microphotos/_microphoto.html.erb`.

To have all microphotos in `home` page, you should probably do:

```
def feed
  Microphoto.all
end
```

in your `User` model.

Comment: thanks, it works! I think I am realy tired as I am working three whole days. I will accept it soon

Comment: would you please answer to the ending q? in this post?

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to link exactly?

Comment: I have another question about this project. I dont want to repeat this whole bunch of data again. As I am new to stackoverflow, is this correct to just ask the other question and link that question to this to provide controllers, models, etc?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I am `really` active here for about month, so I'm not the best person to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try, but please help me more, as this answer just solved part of the problem. I want microphotos from all users on homepage. Now it just show the microphotos from current user

Comment: In my user model I changed `Microphoto.where("user_id = ?", id)` to `Microphoto.all` in `def feed`, but it gives me the error: `undefined method 'paginate'`

Comment: I made it using simply `Microphoto` in `def feed`. Thnkx

Answer (score 0):

`@user.microphotos` is a relation, meaning an array of photos pertaining to the user. What you want to do is iterate over `@user.microphotos` and display each photo, like this

```
<% image_tag @user.microphotos.each do |photoclip| %>
  <li>
    <%= image_tag photoclip.url(:medium) %>
    <span class="content"><%= photoclip.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(photoclip.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  </li>
<% end %>
```